# Unresolved reference: TensorBuffer

Tags: kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to build an app on Android this following Import shows the problem

`import org.tensorflow.lite.TensorBuffer`

I have implemented these on the gradle but No success

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.6.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0-rc1'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:+'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:+'
}
```

Would be very grateful if someone helps.

Tried to Extract text from the Image

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using [TensorFlow Lite Support Library](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support)

In that case you need to add:

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
```